# Is it Just or is it Justice

Tags: meaning

What's the difference between just and justice? The internet is not giving me a very clear answer.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Do you know the difference between nouns, adjectives and adverbs?

Comment: Note that "just" has two entirely different meanings.  One version is the adverb "just" meaning "almost".  The other version is the adjective meaning "honest" or "lawful".  "Justice" is a noun referring to the property of being "just" (in the honest/lawful sense).

Answer (score 2):

Justice is a noun — the notion of things being morally balanced. When the world has a lot of just things (see below), there is justice in the world.

Just is an adjective — when something happens that obeys our laws of morality,it is a just thing.